# Where can I find the @Nullable and/or @NotNull annotations in Java JDK1.6?

Tags: java

Where can I find the java @NotNull and @Nullable annotations. I looked in the javax.annotations namespace but could not find it.

For example

```
    public String(@NotNull String whatever){
     //doSomething
     return whatever;
     }
```

OR

```
    @Nullable public String( String whatever){
     //doSomething
     return whatever
```

Comment: They're not built into the language; you'll need a separate library for them.

Comment: Looking for the library?

Comment: Ok, yes I am looking for the library.

Comment: Thanks @EngineerDollery I looked over that one. It seems to include a variation of third party to one's included in the javax namespace. Messy.

Answer (score 1):

"JSR 305 proposes adding anotations for defect detections, One enhancements proposed in this JSR is a null check annotation, Find Bugs and IntelliJ already provides support for this. When you use the @NotNull annotation you are defining that your code will not except a null parameter, if you were to provide a null parameter, the annotation would throw a RuntimeException. IntelliJ has integrated its use into the IDE, hence at compile time you you can be warned when you are about to assign NULL to a field that has been annotated as @NotNull."

fonte: http://robaustin.wikidot.com/annotations-and-notnull